# Python+Pillow が EMF 画像ファイルを誤って開くという問題に直面しています。

Tags: python, pillow

Python+Pillow が EMF 画像ファイルを誤って開くという問題に直面しています。

まず、MS-Word 文書に Office Math を使用して数式を作成します。

次に、VBA コードを実行して EMF イメージ ファイルを作成します。

(VBA code)

```
Set equation = ActiveDocument.OMaths(1)
equation.Range.Select
Selection.Cut
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

3 番目に、Python コード (”zipfile”) を実行して Word ファイルから EMF 画像ファイルを取得し、それを Pillow で開きます。

(Python code)

```
for file in zipped_files:
if file.startswith(image_folder):
img_file = docx_zip.open(file)
img_bytes = img_file.read()
img_path = img_dir / Path(file).name
with img_path.open(mode="wb") as f3:
f3.write(img_bytes)
img_file.close()
*snip*
img = Image.open("image1.emf")
img.show()
```

表示される数式はなぜか横方向に30%～70%程度縮小して表示されます。

ただし、他のビューア (Irfan View、MS-Paint など) は、MS-Word 文書から取得した EMF 画像ファイルを縮小せずに正しく開くことができます。

私のPC環境は以下の通りです。

Windows 11
Word 2019
Python 3.11.1
Pillow 9.5.0

Python+Pillow で EMF 画像ファイルを正しく表示するにはどうすればよいですか?

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ぜひご教示ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 同じ問題に遭遇し・解決し, この質問をたまたま見かけた人なら回答してくれるかもしれません。でもサンプル EMF 画像をここか別のどこかへアップし, 本来のアスペクト比と間違って解釈されてしまうアスペクト比の情報を質問に記せば, 答えやすいかもしれません(答えてくれる人が出てくるかもしれない)

Comment: Pillowのドキュメントにデフォルトでは72dpiでロードされると書いてあります。違う解像度にしたい場合は`load`メソッドでdpiを指定すれば良いという感じで書かれています。[WMF, EMF](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#wmf-emf) そういう意味で言えばVBAで画像を作成する際にdpi等の指定が出来るのでは？ どちらでやるのが良いか試してみてはどうでしょう？ 逆にEMFファイルをPythonで作成することに関する記事もあるので何か参考になるかも。[Python3を使用して.jpgファイルを.emfファイルに変換する方法。](https://teratail.com/questions/236513) それからおそらくマルチポスト [Python+Pillow+EMFファイル について教えてください。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13281776298)

Comment: あとこんな記事が何か参考になるかも。[Extracting Width/Height Dimensions from EMF Image Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3391087/9014308)